# Got Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/ while hitting api

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am using node as backend and redis as caching server. my redis server and redis cli is up and running. when in hit api to redis server. it throws a error

here is the full error this i got while running api.

```js
DB CONNECTED
Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/
    at Socket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:487:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)      
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) 
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
  bytesParsed: 0,
  code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT',
  reason: 'Expected HTTP/',
  rawPacket: <Buffer 2d 45 52 52 20 77 72 6f 6e 67 20 6e 75 6d 62 65 72 20 6f 66 20 61 72 67 75 6d 65 6e 74 73 20 66 6f 72 20 27 67 65 74 27 20 63 6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64 0d 0a ... 134 more bytes>,
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.24.0'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:2000/api/relevant-jobs',
    data: undefined
  },
}
```